# RAM memory size info confusion; F2 key or "System Setting"?

Tags: ram, bios

I am receiving two different figures for my RAM size.

I have installed 2x2GB RAM and F2 key says I have 4028MB but Ubuntu System Setting "Detail" aka "About this computer" says I only have 2,9G.  I also checked `lshw` on the terminal and it says 3008MB is the memory size. This I think is compatible with the system setting.  Which one should I believe?

I use `Toshiba Satellite p200-143` and there is no doubt the max should be 4G.  OS is `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and I have installed `64 bit`.

I also checked BIOS and as far as I know, version 1.70 is the best I can flash with this laptop and I have done that (directly to the latest, skipping the older version, if makes any difference, I don't know).  Please enlighten me if you have any idea what is going on.  Many thanks.:)

Comment: What's the output of `uname -m`? You could also reboot, and pick the memtest option in the GRUB menu and run some memory tests.

Comment: hi, what shall I type before "-m"?  and could you tell me how to get to GRUB menu?

Comment: Type `uname` - as it looks like. It's a command for displaying system information (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/uname.1). When you reboot, hold shift. You'll be shown a menu with some entries, one of which should be `memtest86+`.

Comment: ok I did "uname -m" and all I got is "x86_64".  Is this right?

Comment: Yes, just checking if you actually had 64-bit. Now try the `memtest`. It's possible your RAM might be faulty.

Comment: ok I did memtest86. It says memory is 3070MB and 2803MB/s  Chipset is Intel and ECC disabled (whatever that means) and 512k e820 off (whatever that means). There is no much else. Is this the test?

Answer (score 2):

**Second Edit:** Here is the [Microsoft Technet article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929605) that explains the problem.

About the two figures:

1. The F2 key reports what size motherboard BIOS sees for the `physically installed` memory in the computer;
2. The second number that you see (in "Detail" and the result of `lshw`) is the actual size of RAM that the loaded operating system (OS) can use for running programs.

Both are correct and the existence of the big difference is OK.

Here is the explanation:

Your computer is using `Intel® 945PM Express chipset`. This is the [official specifications](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-p200-143/) of your computer. `Intel 945PM chipset` has [32-bit physical memory addressing ability](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/309219.pdf). See page 23 from the PDF document, the text is "32-bit interface to address up to 4 GB of memory". So your computer can physically handle only 4GB of addressable RAM space and this don't change regardless using `32-bit` or `64-bit kernel`. Various systems and devices need to reserve some RAM address space in order to work. For example the `PCI-Express` bus needs 256MB of RAM address space. The video card needs additional 256/512MB depending on the model and the implementation. [There was](http://www.cnet.com/news/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-late-2006-3-more-on-why-units-are-limited-to-3-gb-ram/) similar problem with `MacBook Pros`. If you have 3GB RAM in your system that is not a problem because the PCI-Express and videocard address spaces are allocated just before the end of RAM i.e. above 3GB. But when you have 4GB, the memory controller has to disable the access to the RAM on addresses between the 4GB and where these buffer space starts.

Here is an illustration of the problem. I don't know the guy but it should help to illustrate what is going on. This is the [original post](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/motherboard-chipsets-memory-map/).

[image]

**Edit:**
You can check how the address space is allocated by the command `cat /proc/iomem`. And here is Stackoverflow question how to [understand the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469549/understanding-proc-iomem).

This problem will not occure on systems equiped with Intel 965 chipset. It can handle more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This is Computer Science 101 material. You never can have full 4 GB of RAM available, because the system will cache some memory for peripherals , such as keyboard, monitor, touchpad, etc., and there has to be some cached for kernel. It doesn't matter which OS, it's more of the way computers are built.

For instance I have 6 GB (one 2GB stick and 4 GB ), but `free -h` reports 5.6 GB. It's totally normal behavior

Comment: Installing 6G and getting 5.6G seems very normal, indeed. OS using 400MB, that is normal.  I seriously doubt Ubuntu14.04 using 1.1G memory. Hence the question. can you explain why the same OS use up 400MB in ur computer but 1.1GB in mine?  I would never have questioned this if it was using mere 400MB.  Did you really use my description?

Comment: I repeat: out of 4G, I get only 2.9G.  1.1G missing. I.1GB. Is this normal? and how do you explain the descrepancy btw F2 key figure and lshw figure?

Comment: Please read before giving an answer. I would never have been surprised to have a few hundred of MB used up by OS.  THAT is basic.  I am talking about 1.1 G missing.